# Prove that if R and S are sets, then R x S is also a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to get into discrete mathematics.
I want to prove that if R and S are sets, then R x S is also a set. I learnt earlier about the extensionality principle:

$$ R = S \iff \forall x(x \in R \iff x \in S) $$

How do I use this principle to prove above problem?

Comment: What's your definition of $\times$? I don't think this needs proving.

Comment: @SeanRoberson The cartesian product.

Comment: Unless you're studying axiomatic set theory, this is like asking "Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are numbers, then $a+b$ is also a number". Are you sure this is what you wanted to ask? What's the context, and why do you think it has something to do with extensionality?

Comment: @JackM I'm currently in the hospital and working through the script of my professor. I called a friend and she told me to also read through set-existence principles to be able to solve this problem. The exercise was misplaced by our prof and showed up too early.

Comment: @Kris Okay. It doesn't sound like you're studying discrete mathematics, it sounds like you're studying axiomatic set theory. As explained in the answers below, the prove that the cartesian product exists and is a set, in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory you need the axioms of Union, Power Set, Pairing, and Specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing here is that we want to use the schema of specification - we want to show that ordered pairs $(r,s)$, where $r\in R$, $s\in S$, can be separated from a certain set.
The proof here depends on how you define an ordered pair. I will show for 
$(r,s) = \{\{r\},\{r,s\}\}$.
We take $r\in R$, $s\in S$.
So $\{r\} \subset R$, $\{r,s\} \subset R\cup S$.
Then $\{r\} \in P(R)$, $\{r,s\} \in P(R\cup S)$.
So $\{r\},\{r,s\} \in P(R\cup S)$, because every subset of $R$ is a subset of $R\cup S$.
We conclude that $(r,s) = \{\{r\},\{r,s\}\} \subset P(R\cup S)$, which means
$(r,s) = \{\{r\},\{r,s\}\} \in P(P(R\cup S))$.
ZFC axioms guarantee that we can take sum of sets $R,S$ and that we can take power sets.
So $R\times S$ is a set, because we can use schema of specification to state:
$R\times S = \{ a\in P(P(R\cup S)): \exists r\in R, s\in S$ such that $a = \{\{r\},\{r,s\}\}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The extensionality axiom tells you how equality of sets is related to the membership relation.

To show that a collection of elements is a set, the common strategies are to either use a subset axiom or a replacement axiom. The former is used if you can see your collection as a sub-collection of a larger collection that you know is a set, while the latter is used if you can obtain your collection $C$ from a set $S$ by replacing each element $S$ with an element of $C$ so that every element of $C$ is obtained by replacing at least one element of $S$.

In your case, use a subset axiom.

**Hint:** Recall what an ordered pair is as a set. Then use power sets to get it.

If you're stuck, you can take a look at pages 37-38 of Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*.